# use python to read xml one block at a time

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am very new to Python and have the following XML. I want to be able to read each testdata block (one at a time) and be able to read the children within the testdata block. Basically, I would like to read the file and take each testdata block one at a time, based on the row number ( row=1 ), if (execute= no) then skip that entire test data block. Next go read the children of testdata and get the value of the  lines. Next, read get the value of search and the value of found. once all that is read, I will write my own code to do whatever I want with it. Once that code is done, we will go back to the  with row=2 and read the same as in row1 and run my own code that I wrote and so on until all the testdata blocks are read. I am using Python2.7 and would really appreciate your help as I am stuck!

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<data>
<testdata row="1" execute="yes" regression = "no">
    <command>Text command1</command>
    <command> Text command2</command>    
    <command> Text command3</command>
    <command> Text command4</command>
    <command> Text command5</command>
    <command> Text command6</command>
    <command> Text command7</command>
    <command> Text command8</command>
    <verification> search ="verify" found ="yes" </verification>
</testdata>

<testdata row="2" execute="yes" regression = "no">
    <command>Display Command 1</command>
    <command>Display Command 2</command>    
    <command>Display Command 3</command>
    <command>Display Command 4</command>
    <command>Display Command 5</command>
    <command>Display Command 6</command>
    <command>Display Command 7</command>
    <command>Display Command 8</command>
    <verification> search ="find" found ="yes" </verification>
</testdata>
</data>
```

Comment: Have you looked into either BeautifulSoup or the `etree` library? Both of them could do what you want with only a few commands. https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built-in `etree` library is probably going to be a big help here. You could do something like this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("my_file.xml")   # iterparse would process one element at a time
root = tree.getroot()

for testdata in root.findall("testdata"):
    if testdata.get("execute") == "yes":
        command_list = []
        for command in testdata.findall("command"):
            command_list.append(command.text)
        verify = testdata.find("verification").text
        # Insert your code here.
```

Also, instead of `<verification> search ="verify" found ="yes" </verification>`, your file would be easier to parse as `<verification search ="verify" found ="yes" />`. Then you could use something like `verification.get("search")`.

More info can be found here (and I took some of the code from here as well):

https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

Comment: You should also look at the `iterparse` function, which can yield each node one at a time as it's completed (and/or, if you prefer, as it's started, but then you don't have the children yet). In some cases it can be more readable, although of course sometimes it has the opposite effect. (Also, if you have a huge XML file, it can make a huge difference in performance to process it iterably instead of parsing the whole thing and then searching it, but for the files you're looking at that doesn't seem relevant.)

Comment: @abarnert I wasn't aware of that one, I added a comment.

Comment: One question: the `findall` function returns a list. Why are you iterating over that list to build an identical list? (Even if you wanted to make sure it's a list rather than some other iterable, why not just `list(…)`?)

Comment: @abarnert we're making a list of the text specifically. I suppose they could iterate over `list(testdata.findall("command"))` and just call the `.text` on each element. Either way would work.

Comment: @abarnert Thank you for your suggestions. They are helpful.

Comment: @TheSoundDefense: Sorry, didn't notice that… Never mind.

Answer (score -1):

If you use the etree library and parse this data, you can have the following:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
parsed_element = ET.fromstring(xml)
for child in parsed_element.findall('testdata'):
    if child.get('execute') == 'yes':
        print "Execute something on child here"
```